# Hyperlink network analysis in R - measuring the 'reachability' of a vertex within a network?

Tags: r, networking, analysis

I'm trying to conceptualise a network analysis problem and figure out where to start in terms of analysis techniques in R. Apologies as I'm fairly new to all this.

Basically, I have a network (1022 vertices and 9171 edges) which is a hyperlink network of different websites. I want to know if I start at a random vertex in the network (*u*), how many hops (i.e. clicking on hyperlinks) will it take to get to from *u* to my chosen vertex (*v*).

Hence, if I iterate this say 1000 times each with a random assignment of *u*, it might provide some kind of diagnostic around how 'reachable' *u* is. I could then run this on different networks, to see compare reachability of a particular type of vertex *u*.

In less abstract terms I am analysing government websites and the hyperlink networks they are part of. So I'm trying to compare different websites in terms of their reachability in the network - i.e. who's more reachable? I understand there is a wealth of network analysis techniques out there, but I'm at a loss where to start really...

Answer (score 1):

I will assume your question is where to start looking. One of my favorite places is package `sos`. Another option would be [www.rseek.org](http://www.rseek.org).

```
library(sos)
findFn("reachability network analysis")

found 9 matches;  retrieving 1 page

Downloaded 8 links in 3 packages.


Id  Count   MaxScore    TotalScore  Package Function    Date    Score   Description and Link
1   4   5   10  sna 00Index NA  5    Tools for Social Network Analysis
2   4   5   10  sna hierarchy   NA  2    Compute Graph Hierarchy Scores
3   4   5   10  sna reachability    NA  2    Find the Reachability Matrix of a Graph
4   4   5   10  sna prestige    NA  1    Calculate the Vertex Prestige Scores
5   3   1   3   ergm    gof.ergm    NA  1    Conduct Goodness-of-Fit Diagnostics on a Exponential Family...
6   3   1   3   ergm    plot.gofobject  NA  1    Plot Goodness-of-Fit Diagnostics on a Exponential Family...
7   3   1   3   ergm    summary.gofobject   NA  1    Summaries the Goodness-of-Fit Diagnostics on a Exponential...
8   1   1   1   latentnet   gof.ergmm   NA  1    Conduct Goodness-of-Fit Diagnostics on a Exponential Family...
```

Comment: Thank you! I have looked at the 'sos' package and found that exponential random graph models (ERGM) might be a good place to start for answering the research problem here.